# How to include Facebook login in my website?

Tags: php, facebook, web, authentication

im trying to import "log in with facebook" opportunity to my website, im using http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication, but still can not make it work.
I register my website and have app id and app secret.
I have the following code in my login form:

```
 <a href="facebook.php"><img src="images/fb-login-button.png" /></a>
```

facebook.php file:

```
<?php 

$app_id = 1000000000000;
$app_secret = "asdasdasdasd";
$my_url = "http://xxxx.xx/";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&client_secret="
    . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" . $access_token;

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

echo("Hello " . $user->name);
?>
```

It returns message "undefined index code" and I have no idea where and what to change.

Please, help!

Comment: `$app_secret` should be secret ;)

Comment: @Blender You know nothing is ever deleted from SO, right ;)

Comment: This eases the life of the Russian Hackers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is telling you that the "code" parameter you're looking for in the request:

> $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

is not being submitted.. E.g. you either need to post "code" to the page or pass it via GET using facebook.php?code=something

To avoid running into errors when the parameter "code" is not sent, your code could look like:

```
if(!isset( $_REQUEST["code"] ) ) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
} else {
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thank you. :) It fix undefined index problem, but now facebook return message: "An error occurred. Please try again later.":(

Comment: See my demo. I'm not exactly sure what you mean, so I made what I think you meant: http://jsfiddle.net/FTfSq/9/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with Facebook connect, but it looks like you may need the $code to be sent and right now it's being sent empty every time.. Additionally, you might want to die() after you echo that <script>..

Comment: @juand do you know how can I save the details I get from facebook to my database? I am using the same code above

Comment: @IvorySantos that's a little bit vague... It sounds like you need to ask a new SO question and add more details.